# mainmenu.area in nav causing white gap on the right in mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

The white gap seems to be a popular issue. Yet I dont seem to be able to solve it with conventional solutions.

link to website https://bomengeduld.github.io/debadkamers/

link to style.css: https://github.com/bomengeduld/debadkamers/blob/master/style.css

> (use inspector in mobile view) to detect the bug:

```
.mainmenu-area {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


html,
body {

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px !important;
padding: 0px !important;

}
```

> When I use the following it gets fixed, but then I loose the styling of menu bar.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my problem

```
.container {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```